# How to dynamically change value of a nested object

Tags: javascript, json, object, dynamic-programming

Consider I have the following object:

```js
let garages = [{
  "name": "garage LA",
  "cars": [{
      "car": "Ferrari",
      "color": "Red"
    },
    {
      "car": "Rolls Royce",
      "color": "Purple"
    },
    {
      "car": "Ferrari",
      "color": "Orange"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "garage SF",
  "cars": [{
      "car": "Mercedes",
      "color": "Blue"
    },
    {
      "car": "Ferrari",
      "color": "Red"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "garage NY",
  "cars": [{
    "car": "Aston Martin",
    "color": "Green"
  }]
}]
```

I'd like to have a function that could update a specific part of the object dynamically.
For instance `updateObject("Pink", [1, "cars", 1, "color"])` would basically be the same as doing `garages[1]["cars"][1]["color"] = "Pink"` But I do not know how many elements there will be in the array.. And I want the whole object to be returned (with that minor change).

I tried reduce but when passing the object I guess it becomes a shallow copy and nothing really happened..

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems rather redundant. For the logic to work you would need to have advanced knowledge of the structure of the object in order to pass the array `[1, "cars", 1, "color"]` to the second argument. Therefore your code is not any more convenient than just accessing and updating the object directly.

Comment: you could use recursion: `const updateObjectGen = (obj, val, path) => {path.length > 1 ? updateObjectGen(obj[path.shift()], val, path) : obj[path[0]] = val};` with `const updateObject = updateObject(garages)`

Comment: Rory, I will be very aware of the structure. But I cannot update the object like so, since the variable is a useState-variable in react.

Comment: Kikon, I've tried something similar but don't know how to return the full object